# Jquery selector finds the DOM element but native javascript selector returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-selectors

I was using the native Javascript selector on a div element like following

```
var slider_image=document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
    slider_image.style.opacity=0;
```

This returns me uncaught typo error. Cannot set the opacity of undefined. However, when I find the div element using the selector in the console, I get the DOM. But again I can't set the opacity values as it shows the same error.

However, the jquery selector perfectly does the job. What is the problem here?

Could anyone suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `querySelectorAll` returns a list and list doens't have the properties you are looking for.

Where as Jquery maintains the collections of selected Objects and do things internally and apply the changes you asked for.

However you can do the same with Native script aswell. All you need to do is iterate over the returned list and apply the styles on each object instead of applying it to the list directly.